# Не подхватываются пути в header и в слайдере (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Перенес сайт wordpress на локалку, залил дамп базы, прописал пути, все как полагается.
И появилась такая проблема - применились стили и подгрузились картинки везде, кроме header и самой первой секции блока main.
В первой секции так же расположен слайдер, который с некоторой периодичностью меняет картинки, их так же нет.
Если есть какие-то идеи, поделитесь, пожалуйста. Пути все перепроверил, переустанавливал и перебивал их заново,непонятно, почему не коннектятся только эти блоки, в то время, как с остальными все успешно.

Comment: Немного не дописал. Проблема именно в том, что динамически не подгружается родительская директория в путь. Везде подгружается, а именно здесь нет. Хотя код вызова идентичный

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, пожалуйста, и добавьте в него текст комментария.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220